# Invalid SOAPAction in ASP.net Storefront

Tags: soap, aspdotnetstorefront

What is the right SOAPAction for this request to ASPDotNetStoreFront?

```
< POST http://192.168.122.3/ASPDNSF0/ipx.asmx
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.05
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPAction: "http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/DoItUsernamePwd"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap12:Body>
    <DoitUsernamePwd xmlns="http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/">
      <AuthenticationEmail>admin@aspdotnetstorefront.com</AuthenticationEmail>
      <AuthenticationPassword>Admin$11</AuthenticationPassword>
      <XMLInputRequestString>
        <ASPDotNetStorefrontImport Version="7.1">
          <Product action="Add">
            <Name>my product name</Name>
            <SKU>1234</SKU>
            <Description><![CDATA[please
add some <b>data</b>]]></Description>
          </Product>
        </ASPDotNetStorefrontImport>
      </XMLInputRequestString>
    </DoitUsernamePwd>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 22:34:31 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Content-Length: 1938
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Client-Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 20:34:32 GMT
Client-Peer: 192.168.122.3:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/fault</wsa:Action><wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:e8b22878-f37a-4362-8167-441ebab5be00</wsa:MessageID><wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:18b7b7e3-7f65-4622-b093-a906a76b3aba</wsa:RelatesTo><wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To><wsse:Security><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-cd79b88a-3552-4d91-a8d7-d9e3cff73d73"><wsu:Created>2013-09-17T22:34:31Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2013-09-17T22:39:31Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security></env:Header><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at Microsoft.Web.Services3.WseProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean&amp; abortProcessing)</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

must be http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/DoItUsernamePwd
the same webservice says:

SOAPAction: "http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/DoItUsernamePwd"

put the error code for see the ploblem 
good luck

Comment: I had tried that, it appears that this also has to do with the fact that in my XML I had made the typo `DoitUsernamePwd`

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in your code,
What do you call the web service method?

Comment: ... this was the full http request... that in what I posted. Between this and my comment though, /this/ is resolved.